# How to use simplehtmldom to extract data from this page

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I am trying to extract information from https://benthamopen.com/browse-by-title/B/1/ using simplehtmldom.

Specifically, I want to access the parts of the page that says:

```html
<div style="padding:10px;">
<strong>ISSN: </strong>1874-1207<br><div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons" style="padding-top:10px;" data-url="https://benthamopen.com/TOBEJ/home/" data-title="The Open Biomedical Engineering Journal"></div>
</div>
```

I have this code:

```php
$html = file_get_html('https://benthamopen.com/browse-by-title/B/1/');

foreach($html->find('div[style=padding:10px;]') as $ele) {
    echo("<pre>".print_r($ele,true)."</pre>");
}
```

... which returns (I only show one item from the page)

```
simplehtmldom\HtmlNode Object
(
    [nodetype] => HDOM_TYPE_ELEMENT (1)
    [tag] => div
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [style] => padding:10px;
        )

    [nodes] => Array
        (
            [0] => simplehtmldom\HtmlNode Object
                (
                    [nodetype] => HDOM_TYPE_ELEMENT (1)
                    [tag] => strong
                    [attributes] => none
                    [nodes] => none
                )

            [1] => simplehtmldom\HtmlNode Object
                (
                    [nodetype] => HDOM_TYPE_TEXT (3)
                    [tag] => text
                    [attributes] => none
                    [nodes] => none
                )

            [2] => simplehtmldom\HtmlNode Object
                (
                    [nodetype] => HDOM_TYPE_ELEMENT (1)
                    [tag] => br
                    [attributes] => none
                    [nodes] => none
                )

            [3] => simplehtmldom\HtmlNode Object
                (
                    [nodetype] => HDOM_TYPE_ELEMENT (1)
                    [tag] => div
                    [attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => sharethis-inline-share-buttons
                            [style] => padding-top:10px;
                            [data-url] => https://benthamopen.com/TOBEJ/home/
                            [data-title] => The Open Biomedical Engineering Journal
                        )

                    [nodes] => none
                )

        )

)
```

I am unsure how to proceed from here. I want to extract:

- the ISSN text (which does not show in the echo statement - not sure why) [1874-1207 in the above example]. It is element zero of [nodes]
- the 'data-url' [https://benthamopen.com/TOBEJ/home/, in the above example]
- the 'data-title' [The Open Biomedical Engineering Journal, in the above example]

Perhaps my understanding of PHP objects and arrays is not as good as it should be, and I do not know why the ISSN does not show in the echo statement.

I have tried various (many) things, but just struggling to extract the data from the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with simplehtmldom, other than to know to avoid it. So I'll present a solution that uses PHP's built-in DOM classes:

```php
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
// get the HTML
$html = file_get_contents("https://benthamopen.com/browse-by-title/B/1/");

// create a DOM object and load it up
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);

// create an XPath object and query it
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("//div[@style='padding:10px;']");

// loop through the matches
foreach ($elements as $el) {
    // skip elements without ISSN
    $text = trim($el->textContent);
    if (strpos($text, "ISSN") !== 0) {
        continue;
    }
    // get the first div inside this thing
    $div = $el->getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    // dump it out
    printf("%s %s %s<br/>\n", str_replace("ISSN: ", "", $text), $div->getAttribute("data-title"), $div->getAttribute("data-url"));
}
```

The XPath stuff can be a bit overwhelming, but for simple searches like this it's not much different than the CSS selectors. Hopefully the comments explain everything, let me know if not!

Output:

```
1874-1207 The Open Biomedical Engineering Journal https://benthamopen.com/TOBEJ/home/<br/>
1874-1967 The Open Biology Journal https://benthamopen.com/TOBIOJ/home/<br/>
1874-091X The Open Biochemistry Journal https://benthamopen.com/TOBIOCJ/home/<br/>
1875-0362 The Open Bioinformatics Journal https://benthamopen.com/TOBIOIJ/home/<br/>
1875-3183 The Open Biomarkers Journal https://benthamopen.com/TOBIOMJ/home/<br/>
2665-9956 The Open Biomaterials Science Journal https://benthamopen.com/TOBMSJ/home/<br/>
1874-0707 The Open Biotechnology Journal https://benthamopen.com/TOBIOTJ/home/<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks again. I have not been to "convert this to Simple HTML DOM, but solution does what I need and I am VERY grateful.

Still be interested if somebody can say how to do it in Simple HTML DOM, as this might be useful to others, as well as me in the future.